# Can´t find extension causing JQuery conflict on joomla site

Tags: jquery, joomla

I have a Joomla site running **j2.5** and Some unknown extension is loading http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js on my site.

This is causing issues, so i have to find out what extension is doing that and disable the loading of jQuery.

The Bug: I get an error displaying of gallerys in articles.

They show don´t show in lightbox style anymore as they used to. Now when i click on a picture in the gallery, it just reloads the page showing only the picture.

http://streetdome.dk/the-streetdome-project

But i can´t find out what is loading tha JQuery.

Anybody that can help me?

Comment: Try disabling each extension 1 by 1

Answer (score 0):

Start by disabling the component **Ad Agency**.

*Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of **403 (Forbidden)**.*
http://streetdome.dk//images/stories/ad_agency/0/

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple things to address - I know Joomla is moving towards JQuery integration and getting rid of (or using significantly less of) Mootools.  I cannot recall if JQuery is included in 2.5 or if it's 3.x+; you may want to look into that.  I do not believe it is in 2.5 however.

The other thing is - how many extensions have you added?  Most likely you'll have to look into each one.  Since it's being loaded by one of them, you'll have to look at the sites for each of them to see who is using jquery.  Or the alternative method is to go through the plugins that you're unsure of and turn them off 1 at a time to see if jQuery is no longer being loaded.  Eventually you'll stumble across the one that is doing it.

Worst case scenario?  Maybe you have a couple/few extensions that are loading jQuery so it could be more tricky.

The other option is to look into the error and see if it's something you can fix on your site to make it compatible with the jquery (since the extension probably requires it to work properly).

Lastly, don't be afraid to reach out to the developer of the extension once you figure out which one it is and see if they have a non-jquery version and alert them to the issue with your site.

P.S. - I always recommend upgrading to the latest Joomla and keeping it as up to date on any version to ensure a secure site!